# How to open pdf files in swt Browser composite

Tags: java, pdf, browser, swt

I have created a browser using swt Browser, but if I set a URL that is a pdf file it only display a black X in the top left corner. Is there a solution to make the browser display the pdf?

Comment: Are you sure your URL is correct? URL().toExternalForm() ?

Comment: I had only called browser.setUrl(String url), I hadn't created a URL

Comment: How do you retrieve URL string?

Comment: I have a string with the url

Comment: This is my new code 
Browser browser = new Browser(parent, SWT.BORDER);
browser.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
browser.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH));
  try {
   URL url = new URL("http://www.gradsch.ohio-state.edu/depo/etd_tutorial/lesson2.pdf");
   browser.setUrl(url.toExternalForm());
  } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e1.printStackTrace();
  }'

Comment: Ok, in this case using URL object does not make any sense. Simply use Browser browser = new Browser(composite, SWT.NONE); browser.setUrl("http://www.gradsch.ohio-state.edu/depo/etd_tutorial/lesson2.pdf"); It works for me. If it doesn't work for you there may be Adobe Reader and your IE compatibility issue. Do you have latest versions of both programs?

Comment: I have the latest versions for both IE and Adobe Reader. On the IE the pdf is shown. Thanks a lot anyway.